# New Magic Keyboard "feel"

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I currently use the Apple Wired Keyboard (Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad), MC110LL/B. It is fairly large on my desk. I never use the numeric keypad, and could live with small cursor keys. The MB869LL/A would be fine, but they no longer make it.

So, looking for something compact, I tried the older version of the wireless keyboard, MC184LL/B. I returned it. It had absolutely *terrible* key feel. My typo rate soared.

Can anyone with the new Magic Keyboard, MLA22LL/A, who has used the older wired keyboard comment on the keys feel in comparison? I am specifically asking about the "throw" of the key travel of the two, and the force. The throw on the wireless was fine compared to my wired, but the force was much greater than the wired.

**Note:** I am asking for quantitative comparisons, not opinions.

Comment: Have you tried tracking down a used Apple Bluetooth Keyboard (non-magic)? I know used peripherals tend to be ick, but I have some peers who had success with this recently.

Comment: I have never found one available in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

The current 2016 Bluetooth magic keyboard has larger keys so your press feels lighter even though I believe the stiffness is either the same absolutely or perhaps a bit stiffer if you were to calculate or measure the force.

Structurally, the scissors are more even and the keys don't wobble as much. If you hated the old one, the new one is sufficiently different that you should probably spend the time test driving one or buy from Apple with their 14 day, no questions asked return policy.

You may not love it, but you can type enough to let your initial impressions fade and them make a decision based on how your typing adjusts to the keyboard. Someone who likes a mechanical keyboard probably isn't going to like any of Apple's current keyboards.

Comment: *keyboard has larger keys* - than the apple wired, or the older BT? I think the wired is also scissors, no?